# monacaでbackendを設定したときだけビルドがうまくいきません

Tags: monaca, build

現在monacaでプッシュ通知に関するテストアプリを作成しています。
ビルドして動作を確かめようとしたところ、
添付画像のようなエラー画面が出現し、ビルドが失敗してしまいます。
[image: ビルド失敗]
backendとの接続を切ったところビルドに成功したためbackendに原因があるようですが、解決方法がわかりません。

どなたか原因が分かる方はいますでしょうか。

追記: ビルド時のメッセージを追記しています。　※IDは置換しています

> Temporary folder: /private/tmp/monaca/******************
>   Downloading project
>   Download complete
>   Running for 4.1
>   Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.Monaca" for android
>   cordova version not detected (lacks script "/private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version" ), continuing.
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" for android
>   Installing "plugin.push.nifty" for android
>   cordova version not detected (lacks script "/private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version" ), continuing.
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.dialogs" for android
>   Installing "mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend" for android
>   cordova version not detected (lacks script "/private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/version" ), continuing.
>   Updated local.properties
>   No project name specified, using project folder name 'google-play-services_lib'.
>   If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
>   Added file /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend/google-play-services_lib/build.xml
>   Added file /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend/google-play-services_lib/proguard-project.txt
>   Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/hooks/after_prepare/monaca_enterprise_encrypt.js /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton
>   Running command: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build --debug
>   Buildfile: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.xml
>   -set-mode-check:
>   -set-debug-files:
>   -check-env:
>    [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.2
>    [checkenv] Installed at /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk
>   -setup:
>        [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
>     [gettype] Project Type: Application
>   -set-debug-mode:
>   -debug-obfuscation-check:
>   -pre-build:
>   -build-setup:
>   [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 20.0.0
>        [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
>   [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
>   [gettarget] API level:        19
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/res
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/rsObj
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/rsLibs
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-gen
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
>       [mkdir] Created dir: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/ant-build/dexedLibs
>        [echo] ----------
>        [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
>   [dependency] Library dependencies:
>   [dependency] 
>   [dependency] ------------------
>   [dependency] Ordered libraries:
>   [dependency] 
>   [dependency] ------------------
>   [dependency] Found 2 versions of google-play-services.jar in the dependency list,
>   [dependency] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
>   [dependency] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
>   [dependency] Versions found are:
>   [dependency] Path: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/mobi.monaca.plugins.MonacaBackend/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar
>   [dependency]    Length: 2264484
>   [dependency]    SHA-1: 3dfdf1db5ce5ea2999a5dcde8c8e650b02660059
>   [dependency] Path: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/libs/google-play-services.jar
>   [dependency]    Length: 1881748
>   [dependency]    SHA-1: 7676c0cb230efa6ac41c47867d372ed5913029d4
>   BUILD FAILED
>   /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:577: Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
>   Total time: 1 second
>   /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^
>   Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
>   Error: /private/tmp/monaca/******************/android/skeleton/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/data/monaca_build_module/4.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
>   Build error: Error building project source code

Comment: ビルド時のログも提示していただけると解決率が上がるかもしれません。

Comment: @cither 
追記致しました。宜しくお願い致します。